# How to fix "You'll need a new app to open this windowsdefender link" when trying to open Windows Defender in Win 11 Preview?

Tags: windows, windows-defender, windows-11-preview

I have upgraded to the Windows 11 Preview through the beta program. Trying to start Windows Defender yields in an error message:

[image: You'll need a new app to open this windowsdefender link]

Googling the issue, there is [supposed to be a fix for Windows 10](https://michaelspice.net/uncategorized/youll-need-a-new-app-to-open-this-windowsdefender/) by running:

```
Add-AppxPackage -Register -DisableDevelopmentMode "C:\Windows\SystemApps\Microsoft.Windows.SecHealthUI_cw5n1h2txyewy\AppXManifest.xml"
```

from an admin power shell.

In Windows 11 preview I get an error though:

```
Add-AppxPackage : Cannot find path
'C:\Windows\SystemApps\Microsoft.Windows.SecHealthUI_cw5n1h2txyewy\AppXManifest.xml' because it does not exist.
At line:1 char:1
+ Add-AppxPackage -Register -DisableDevelopmentMode "C:\Windows\SystemA ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\Windows\Syst...ppXManifest.xml:String) [Add-AppxPackage], ItemNotFou
   ndException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.Windows.Appx.PackageManager.Commands.AddAppxPackageCommand
```

Answer (score 1):

Open an admin powershell and run:

```
Get-AppxPackage Microsoft.SecHealthUI -AllUsers | Reset-AppxPackage
```

[Source](https://www.netzwelt.de/news/192620-windows-11-ohne-sicherheits-app-fehlermeldung-statt-windows-defender.html)

Comment: I got this error:
Reset-AppxPackage : Package was not found. Windows cannot remove Microsoft.SecHealthUI_1000.22000.1.0_neutral__8wekyb3d8bbwe because the current user does not have that package installed. Use Get-AppxPackage to see the list of packages installed. At line:1 char:51 [...]